# Python 2.7 Qt Matplotlib : subplot ID reference from event

Tags: python, events, matplotlib, pyqt, subplot

My goal is to identify which subplot has been clicked on by the user. More precisely in the matplotlib class, I can identify the subplot using event.inaxes. Great. But I cannot get that event in the Qt widget class. 
I am definitely missing something ... 
Here is the code with my latest "awkward" attempt. Any suggestion on how to procceed ?

I am no Python expert. Python 2.7 has to be used (no choice)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.backend_bases import Event
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)

#Connect InventoryChartsWidget to ChartFigure: QT
class TheConnector(QtCore.QObject):

   selecteddataregion=pyqtSignal(name='selecteddataregion')

   def emitsignal(self,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax):
       self.selecteddataregion.emit()

#Chart including events: MATPLOTLIB
class ChartFigure(Figure):

def onclick(self,event):
    #MAIN ISSUE
    #HOW TO RETURN THE subplot axes to class InventoryChartsWidget?    

    if event.button==1 :
       self.ConnSbPlt.emitsignal(1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0)
       print('OK: Axes is ... ', event.inaxes)

def __init__(self,Conn):
    #Init the Matplotlib      
    Figure.__init__(self) #initialize the orginal class, see also super()
    super(ChartFigure, self).__init__()
    self.canvas=FigureCanvas(self)
    self.ConnSbPlt=Conn

#Chart including events: QT  
class InventoryChartsWidget(QtGui.QDialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None,xlimlow=0,xlimhigh=100,ylimlow=0,ylimhigh=100, G_array=[], N_array=[], ddom_array=[], hdom_array=[], speciesDict={}):

    QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

    #Fake stupid data 
    self.mG_array  = [2] * 10
    self.mHdom_array = [0.5] * 10

    #jte to make sur I have it
    self.xdata_start=-1.0

    #fake plot to get a member of type subplot: UGLY!
    #Attempt to create a member object "axes"
    self.tabFake = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tabFake = self.create_tab(self.tabFake)
    self.tabFake.plots = []
    self.subPlotFake = self.tabFake.fig.add_subplot(111)

    print("here is OK; it exists ...", self.subPlotFake)

    self.create_main_frame()

    self.setModal(False)
    self.setVisible(True)
    self.show()


def create_main_frame(self):
    #Associate a Qwidget with the InventoryChartsWidget widget

    print("OK here too; it exists ... ",self.subPlotFake)

    self.main_frame = QtGui.QWidget()
    LesTabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
    self.tabG   = QtGui.QWidget()   

    #Fill the tab with Matplotlib object and draw the charts 
    self.tabG=self.create_tab(self.tabG)
    self.on_draw_G(self.tabG)
    self.tabG.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.02,bottom=0.05,right=1,top=0.95,wspace=0.2,hspace=0.2)

    LesTabs.addTab(self.tabG,"Chart")

    grid = QGridLayout()
    grid.addWidget(LesTabs, 0, 0)
    self.main_frame.setLayout(grid)
    self.setLayout(grid)
    self.layout().addWidget(self.main_frame)


def UpdatePlot_DataSelection(self):
    #SLOT
    print("Get connected here process the data in the subplot XX...")


def on_draw_G(self,tab):
    #Juts one subplot for test purpose
    tab.fig.clear()
    tab.plots = []
    subPlot = tab.fig.add_subplot(111)
    subPlot.hold(False)
    tab.plots.append(subPlot)
    self.PlotData_G(subPlot,self.mG_array,self.mHdom_array)
    subPlot = tab.fig.add_subplot(122)
    subPlot.hold(False)
    tab.plots.append(subPlot)
    self.PlotData_G(subPlot,self.mG_array,self.mHdom_array)
    tab.canvas.draw()    

def create_tab(self,tab):    
    #Create the tab widget, associated with Matplotlib plot

    print("OK member exists ... ", self.xdata_start)
    print("OK member exists ",self.tabFake)

    #ISSUE HERE: don't understand
    #print("NOT OK !!! member does not exist Why ? ",self.subPlotFake)

    Conn=TheConnector()
    #MATPLOTLIB
    tab.fig = ChartFigure(Conn)
    tab.canvas = FigureCanvas(tab.fig)
    tab.canvas.setParent(tab)
    tab.canvas.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    tab.canvas.setFocus()

    #connect signal to slot 
    Conn.selecteddataregion.connect(self.UpdatePlot_DataSelection)

    tab.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(tab.canvas, tab)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(tab.canvas)  
    vbox.addWidget(tab.mpl_toolbar)
    tab.setLayout(vbox)  

    tab.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', tab.fig.onclick)

    return tab    

def on_key_press(self, event):
    #Keyboard input: standard mpl key press
    key_press_handler(event, self.canvas, self.mpl_toolbar)

def PlotData_G(self, plot, G_array, hdom_array):
    # Plot G
    plot.hold(False)
    plot.scatter(x=hdom_array, y=G_array, marker='+',linewidths=1.5)
    plot.set_autoscaley_on(True)
    plot.tick_params(labelsize=8)

def main():
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = InventoryChartsWidget(xlimlow=0,xlimhigh=60,ylimlow=0,ylimhigh=80)
form.show()
app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

There are 3 classes: 
TheConnector is a Signal/Slot QT class
ChartFigure is matplotlib class (including the desired mouse Event)
InventoryChartsWidget is the main widget (Qt; here I need the ID of the subplot)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "Awkward" is probably the correct word. I cannot imagine a case where such a structure would make sense. In order to solve your problem with this code, you'd probably best emit a signal which contains the matplotlib event such that the slot can process it. More generally, I don't see any point in having those three classes and catching the event in one of them just to afterwards transfer it to the other.

Comment: Thank you for a fresh and independent look at the illustration code. This is of course  a very simplified and very short version of the original code to explain the essence of the question. The 3 classes make sense then (at least until the requirements have been changed ... again). About catching the event and transfer it, the reason is to keep a hierarchy instead of an entanglement of classes (-> structure).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. The true limit was my thinking in python (to be more specific the lack of properly declared variables ... can't get use to it)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.backend_bases import Event
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)


#Connect InventoryChartsWidget to ChartFigure: QT
class TheConnector(QtCore.QObject):

   selecteddataregionARG=pyqtSignal(object,name='selecteddataregionIN')

   def emitsignalEvent(self,TheEvent):
       self.selecteddataregionARG.emit(TheEvent)    

#Chart including events: MATPLOTLIB
class ChartFigure(Figure):

def onclick(self,event):
    #MAIN ISSUE
    #HOW TO RETURN THE subplot axes to class InventoryChartsWidget class?    

    if event.button==1 :
       print('Event: Axes is ... ', event.inaxes)
       self.ConnSbPlt.emitsignalEvent(event.inaxes)

def __init__(self,Conn):
    #Init the Matplotlib      
    Figure.__init__(self) #initialize the orginal class, see also super()
    super(ChartFigure, self).__init__()
    self.canvas=FigureCanvas(self)
    self.ConnSbPlt=Conn

#Chart including events: QT  
class InventoryChartsWidget(QtGui.QDialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None,xlimlow=0,xlimhigh=100,ylimlow=0,ylimhigh=100, G_array=[], N_array=[], ddom_array=[], hdom_array=[], speciesDict={}):

    QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

    #Fake stupid data 
    self.mG_array  = [2] * 10
    self.mHdom_array = [0.5] * 10

    #jte to make sur I have it
    self.xdata_start=-1.0

    self.create_main_frame()

    self.setModal(False)
    self.setVisible(True)
    self.show()


def create_main_frame(self):
    #Associate a Qwidget with the InventoryChartsWidget widget

    self.main_frame = QtGui.QWidget()
    LesTabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
    self.tabG   = QtGui.QWidget()   

    #Fill the tab with Matplotlib object and draw the charts 
    self.tabG=self.create_tab(self.tabG)
    self.on_draw_G(self.tabG)
    self.tabG.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.02,bottom=0.05,right=1,top=0.95,wspace=0.2,hspace=0.2)

    LesTabs.addTab(self.tabG,"Chart")

    grid = QGridLayout()
    grid.addWidget(LesTabs, 0, 0)
    self.main_frame.setLayout(grid)
    self.setLayout(grid)
    self.layout().addWidget(self.main_frame)


def UpdatePlot_DataSelection_withArg(self,TheEvent):
    #SLOT
    print("WITH ARG : Get connected here process the data in the subplot XX...",TheEvent)


def on_draw_G(self,tab):
    #Juts one subplot for test purpose
    tab.fig.clear()
    tab.plots = []
    subPlot = tab.fig.add_subplot(111)
    subPlot.hold(False)
    tab.plots.append(subPlot)
    self.PlotData_G(subPlot,self.mG_array,self.mHdom_array)
    subPlot = tab.fig.add_subplot(122)
    subPlot.hold(False)
    tab.plots.append(subPlot)
    self.PlotData_G(subPlot,self.mG_array,self.mHdom_array)
    tab.canvas.draw()    

def create_tab(self,tab):    
    #Create the tab widget, associated with Matplotlib plot

    Conn=TheConnector()
    #MATPLOTLIB
    tab.fig = ChartFigure(Conn)
    tab.canvas = FigureCanvas(tab.fig)
    tab.canvas.setParent(tab)
    tab.canvas.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    tab.canvas.setFocus()

    #connect signal to slot 
    Conn.selecteddataregionARG.connect(lambda who="Three": self.UpdatePlot_DataSelection_withArg(who))

    tab.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(tab.canvas, tab)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(tab.canvas)  
    vbox.addWidget(tab.mpl_toolbar)
    tab.setLayout(vbox)  

    tab.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', tab.fig.onclick)

    return tab    

def on_key_press(self, event):
    #Keyboard input: standard mpl key press
    key_press_handler(event, self.canvas, self.mpl_toolbar)

def PlotData_G(self, plot, G_array, hdom_array):
    # Plot G
    plot.hold(False)
    plot.scatter(x=hdom_array, y=G_array, marker='+',linewidths=1.5)
    plot.set_autoscaley_on(True)

def main():
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = InventoryChartsWidget(xlimlow=0,xlimhigh=60,ylimlow=0,ylimhigh=80)
form.show()
app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Maybe it can help someone ...
We can of course argue if the 3 classes make sense but this is another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could transfer the event to the main class:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)

#Connect InventoryChartsWidget to ChartFigure: QT
class TheConnector(QtCore.QObject):

    selecteddataregion=QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, name='selecteddataregion')

    def emitsignal(self,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax, event):
        self.selecteddataregion.emit((xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax, event))

#Chart including events: MATPLOTLIB
class ChartFigure(Figure):

    def onclick(self,event):
        #MAIN ISSUE
        #HOW TO RETURN THE subplot axes to class InventoryChartsWidget?    

        if event.button==1 :
            print('OK: Axes is ... ', event.inaxes)
            self.ConnSbPlt.emitsignal(1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0, event)


    def __init__(self,Conn):
        #Init the Matplotlib      
        Figure.__init__(self) #initialize the orginal class, see also super()
        super(ChartFigure, self).__init__()
        self.canvas=FigureCanvas(self)
        self.ConnSbPlt=Conn

#Chart including events: QT  
class InventoryChartsWidget(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None,xlimlow=0,xlimhigh=100,ylimlow=0,ylimhigh=100, G_array=[], N_array=[], ddom_array=[], hdom_array=[], speciesDict={}):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        #Fake stupid data 
        self.mG_array  = [2] * 10
        self.mHdom_array = [0.5] * 10

        #jte to make sur I have it
        self.xdata_start=-1.0

        #fake plot to get a member of type subplot: UGLY!
        #Attempt to create a member object "axes"
        self.tabFake = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tabFake = self.create_tab(self.tabFake)
        self.tabFake.plots = []
        self.subPlotFake = self.tabFake.fig.add_subplot(111)

        print("here is OK; it exists ...", self.subPlotFake)

        self.create_main_frame()

        self.setModal(False)
        self.setVisible(True)
        self.show()


    def create_main_frame(self):
        #Associate a Qwidget with the InventoryChartsWidget widget

        print("OK here too; it exists ... ",self.subPlotFake)

        self.main_frame = QtGui.QWidget()
        LesTabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.tabG   = QtGui.QWidget()   

        #Fill the tab with Matplotlib object and draw the charts 
        self.tabG=self.create_tab(self.tabG)
        self.on_draw_G(self.tabG)
        self.tabG.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.02,bottom=0.05,right=1,top=0.95,wspace=0.2,hspace=0.2)

        LesTabs.addTab(self.tabG,"Chart")

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(LesTabs, 0, 0)
        self.main_frame.setLayout(grid)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.main_frame)


    def UpdatePlot_DataSelection(self, transfer_object):
        #SLOT
        xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax, event = transfer_object
        print ("Axes are now in the InventoryChartsWidget: ", event.inaxes)


    def on_draw_G(self,tab):
        #Juts one subplot for test purpose
        tab.fig.clear()
        tab.plots = []
        subPlot = tab.fig.add_subplot(111)
        #subPlot.hold(False)
        tab.plots.append(subPlot)
        self.PlotData_G(subPlot,self.mG_array,self.mHdom_array)
        subPlot = tab.fig.add_subplot(122)
        #subPlot.hold(False)
        tab.plots.append(subPlot)
        self.PlotData_G(subPlot,self.mG_array,self.mHdom_array)
        tab.canvas.draw()    

    def create_tab(self,tab):    
        #Create the tab widget, associated with Matplotlib plot

        print("OK member exists ... ", self.xdata_start)
        print("OK member exists ",self.tabFake)

        #ISSUE HERE: don't understand
        #print("NOT OK !!! member does not exist Why ? ",self.subPlotFake)
        # reason: self.subPlotFake does not yet exist 

        Conn=TheConnector()
        #MATPLOTLIB
        tab.fig = ChartFigure(Conn)
        tab.canvas = FigureCanvas(tab.fig)
        tab.canvas.setParent(tab)
        tab.canvas.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        tab.canvas.setFocus()

        #connect signal to slot 
        Conn.selecteddataregion.connect(self.UpdatePlot_DataSelection)

        tab.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(tab.canvas, tab)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(tab.canvas)  
        vbox.addWidget(tab.mpl_toolbar)
        tab.setLayout(vbox)  

        tab.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', tab.fig.onclick)

        return tab    

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        #Keyboard input: standard mpl key press
        key_press_handler(event, self.canvas, self.mpl_toolbar)

    def PlotData_G(self, plot, G_array, hdom_array):
        # Plot G
        #plot.hold(False) #axes.hold is deprecated.
        plot.scatter(x=hdom_array, y=G_array, marker='+',linewidths=1.5)
        plot.set_autoscaley_on(True)
        plot.tick_params(labelsize=8)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = InventoryChartsWidget(xlimlow=0,xlimhigh=60,ylimlow=0,ylimhigh=80)
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```